# can i get date of friendship in twitter?

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

is there a way to get the date of friendship creation for both my friends and followers in twitter?

especially for python-twitter....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter doesn't preserve the date a friendship or follow is created, and it doesn't return it in  the API. Going forward you can query friends/ids and followers/id every day and record any new relationships with the current date in a database.

Comment: At a stretch, he could check the email notifications if he has access to the account.